# Non-overridable members (here: Login.getInfo) may not be used in setup / verification expressions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I want to write unit test of this code but I always get different errors:

```
public List<string> getInfo(string tableName, string[] getColumsName)
{
    List<string> infoList = new List<string>();
    SqlCommand cm;
    cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from [" + tableName + "]", connect);
    SqlDataReader data;
    connect.Open();
    data = cm.ExecuteReader();
 
    while (data.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < getColumsName.Length; i++)
        {
            infoList.Add(data[getColumsName[i]].ToString());
        }
    }
    return infoList;
}
```

The code I'm trying to write.I used this as unittest code but I guess it's wrong

```
string[] getColumsName = new string[2];
getColumsName[0] = "ıpAdress";
getColumsName[1] = "protocolName";

var mock = new Mock<Login>();
mock.Setup(m => m.getInfo("Asset", getColumsName)).Returns(() => new List<string> {
"192.168.1.18","SNMPV2","192.168.1.18","WMI","192.168.1.191","WMI","192.168.1.191","SNMPV2","192.168.1.125","WNI","192.168.1.125","SNMPV2","192.168.1.6",
"SNMPV2","192.168.1.6","WMI"
});
var resultList = mock.Object.getInfo("Asset", getColumsName);
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new List<string> {
"192.168.1.18","SNMPV2","192.168.1.18","WMI","192.168.1.191","WMI","192.168.1.191","SNMPV2","192.168.1.125","WNI","192.168.1.125","SNMPV2","192.168.1.6",
"SNMPV2","192.168.1.6","WMI"
}, resultList);
```

Comment: Show us your attempts to write tests.

Comment: Sorry , I've edited.tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moq is constrained isolation framework. It can mock only virtual methods.

Extract interface from you `Login` class.

```
public interface ILogin
{
    List<string> GetInfo(string tableName, string[] columnNames);
    // other members
}
```

Add this interface to the class definition.

```
public class Login : ILogin
{
    public List<string> GetInfo(string tableName, string[] columnNames)
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from [" + tableName + "]", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                List<string> infoList = new List<string>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Length; i++)
                    {
                        infoList.Add(reader[columnNames[i]].ToString());
                    }
                }
                return infoList;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mock this interface instead of class.

```
var mock = new Mock<ILogin>();
```